# Filter NSArray of NSNumber with NSArray of NSNumber with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have this custom class:

```
@interface MyModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *id_name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *genres;

@end
```

The genres array is an array of `NSNumber`s. I fill another array with the `MyModel` object, for example:

```
MyModel *m = [[MyModel alloc] init];
m.id_name = @"2345";
m.genres = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],nil];

MyModel *m2 = [[MyModel alloc] init];
m2.id_name = @"259";
m2.genres = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],nil];

MyModel *m3 = [[MyModel alloc] init];
m3.id_name = @"25932as";
m3.genres = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],nil];

myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:m,m2,m3,nil];
```

Now I want to filter `myArray` such that the genres are contained within the elements of this array:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],nil];
```

So, `myArray`, after filtering, should contain the objects `m2` and `m3`. Can I do this with `NSPredicate`? If so, how? Or is there another way?

Comment: Do you want objects that contain *any* of the given array elements, or *all* given array elements?

Comment: all elements if it's possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the objects that have *at least one* genre in the given array `a`, use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY genres in %@", a];
```

To find the objects that have *all* genres in the given array, a SUBQUERY is needed:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(genres, $g, $g IN %@).@count = %d", a, [a count]];
```

(The idea is to check if the number of genres that are in the given array is equal
to the size of the array.)

Comment: i have tried, but seems that doesn't work :( have you tried it?

Comment: @Piero: Yes, I tried it exactly with your code, and it returned `m2` and `m3`.

Comment: @Piero: OK, I will update the answer (that should be easier).

Comment: last question, if the array to check it's of NSString and not of NSNumber?, so genres it's an array of NSString, that contains string of int, and the "a" array remain an array of NSNumber it's possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36137/discussion-between-martin-r-and-piero)

Answer (score 1):

Martin R has provided an elegant answer, but if I understand your question correctly, you can also use a simpler predicate:

```
NSPredicate *allPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ALL %@ IN genres", a];

NSArray *result = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: allPred];
```

This predicate will find `MyModel`s that contain *all* of the genres included in your `a` array. In the case of your test data, that will be the two objects with ids `259` and `25932as`.

Comment: Indeed, that is a simpler alternative for the SUBQUERY. (As it turned out, Piero needed the "any" solution, but that was not clear from the question.)